# ShellExecute makes script to halt

Tags: windows, automation, ui-automation, autoit

I have an exe file which I execute with some command line arguments. Upon execution it first shows a pop up which asks the user "Do you want the following program to make changes to this computer?" If I click Yes, the execution is completed

Now I want to automate this behavior. I am using `ShellExecute` Function in AutoIt to run this function as follow

```
ShellExecute("abc.exe", "-a arg1", "", "")
ConsoleWrite("Execution done")
```

Now because of the popup the script gets stuck at the ShellExecute line and does not proceed until I manually hit Yes or No on the popup. I want to make the click on this popup automated. But since my code does not proceed further, I can't do anything.

Comment: You are asking for a hack around the UAC prompt.  Of course that is not possible, *everybody* would use it.  The prompt is displayed on the secure desktop, you can't poke it.

Comment: Try running AutoIt elevated ("run as administrator") so that it can launch admin processes without prompting.

Comment: #RequireAdmin at the top of your script

Comment: @Milos your solution worked. Thanks. But now it does not print any ConsoleWrite statements in the console. I see that in the docuementation its given that ConsoleWrite will not work. Is there any work around for this.

Comment: Yes, run scite as administrator

Answer (score 1):

@Milos answered it in comments. 
I used #requireAdmin as suggested by Milos and it worked. [check out here about #requreAdmin](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/RequireAdmin.htm)